# SELECT SQL Syntax For Count in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to construct the correct sql statement (Oracle) to get the count of device_id's for each customer_id that is greater than a given value. For example, I want to know the customer_id's that have more than 3 device_ids. A single device_id can only have one customer_id associated to it, while a customer_id may have many device_ids.

```
Table:
device_id
customer_id
....

Data (device_id, customer_id):
00001, CUST1
00002, CUST1
00003, CUST1
00004, CUST1
00005, CUST2
00006, CUST2
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get the customers with more than 3 devices:

```
select customer_id, count(device_id)
from YourTable
Group by customer_id
having count(device_id) > 3
```

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause

```
select customer_id, count(device_id)
from YourTable
group by customer_id
having count(device_id) > 3
```

Comment: I do believe you did not copy my SQL code, I'm just amazed that we both picked the same names and approaches :)

Comment: @Adrian I did not copy yours, when you had initially posted you did not have the `HAVING` clause.  I typically use `yourtable` as my generic name.

Comment: Just as I said before, I really do think there was no copy. The `having` came 10 seconds later, as an edit. It's a simple problem, so same SQL are feasible. I was just really entertained with the exact looks :)

Comment: @Adrian just lucky I guess. :)  Or we all just spend too much time on SO

Comment: I would guess it's the second ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the having clause:

```
select customer_id, count(*)
from t
group by customer_id
having count(*) > 3
```